# How to delete group of strings from fasta

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have fastf

> sp|A0A0B4J2F2|SIK1B_HUMAN Putative serine/threonine-protein kinase SIK1B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=SIK1B PE=5 SV=1
> MVIMSEFSADPAGQGQGQQKPLRVGFYDIERTLGKGNFAVVKLARHRVTKTQVAIKIIDK...
> **>sp|A0A0B4J2F2|SIK1B_HUMAN_VEP Putative serine/threonine-protein kinase SIK1B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=SIK1B PE=5 SV=1**
> MVIMSEFSADPAGQGQGQQKPLRVGFYDIERTLGKGNFAVVKLARHRVTKTQVAIKIIDK..

Both ones have the same sequence, but different id string. I want delete id and strings without _VEP and save id and sequence with _VEP.

I try this one
f2 - file with seq that i need to delete
f1 - file with all seq
grep -v -x -f f2.fasta f1.fasta > f3.fasta

And another variant
awk 'NR==FNR { b[$0] = 1; next } !b[$0]' f2.fasta f1.fasta > f3.fasta

I have this output

> sp|A0A0B4J2F2|SIK1B_HUMAN_VEP Putative serine/threonine-protein kinase SIK1B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=SIK1B PE=5 SV=1 **WITHOUT SEQ**

but i want this one

**>sp|A0A0B4J2F2|SIK1B_HUMAN_VEP Putative serine/threonine-protein kinase SIK1B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=SIK1B PE=5 SV=1**
MVIMSEFSADPAGQGQGQQKPLRVGFYDIERTLGKGNFAVVKLARHRVTKTQVAIKIIDK..

Comment: 101 years ago... I used a perl program `fastgrep` for stuff like this. a quick web search shows there are now many similar options in other languages.      fastagrep input.fa  '_VEP' > output.fa

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting `awk` script:

```
awk -F'|' '$3 ~ "_VEP "{print}' *.fasta
```